# Find in text a sentence with some differences

Tags: python, nltk

I send a large text to ChatGPT and I get back a list of sentences from the text. Some times, ChatGPT modifies the sentences returned, for example removing some additional white space or fixing some grammar errors.
For example, ChatGPT returned the following sentence:

> Communications Class Refers to the medium, protocol, and frequency of
> the mobile wireless

The original text contained:

> OEM E-forms UTC Original Equipment Manufacturer/Manufacturing
> Electronic  forms,  such  as  catch  reporting  or declaration forms
> Universal Time Coordinated *Communications Class Refers  to  the
> mediume,  protocol,  and  frequency  of the mobile wireless*
> communications technology 1.5. Historical Approvals   At present,
> there is already an existing type approved MCSP together with type
> approved MTUs and these MTUs will remain as type approved MTUs only.
> The MCSP of these MTUs

The original text, is emphasized, and has some differences. I want to find the index of that sentence. How can I do that? With a regex it is possible to solve the problem of the white space, but not the small corrections added by ChatGPT.

Comment: If you have only one sentence to look for, and the difference is only the number of spaces ... you can easily use a regexp with module re and look for the partern ... just add a + after spaces ... example of pattern   re.search("Communications +Class +Refers +to +the +medium, +protocol, +and +frequency +of +the +mobile +wireless", text)

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have updated the problem description and i hope that i get much more clear :-)

Comment: I see some differences like "medium" / "mediume" ? if some mistakes are corrected is more difficult or impossible to find a match. What kind of differences do you expect ? blank is quite easy to handle ... spelling mistakes is harder. please be more specific. So you just want the starting index of the ChatGPT sentence. Can you ask ChatGPT / prompt to return only the corrected version of first sentence ?

Comment: I already asked to GPT to return the correct sentence, and as usual, sometimes work and others no. the medium and mediume in intential, the problem is th spelling mistake, yes. at the moment i don't have found any solution and seems that is not harder but impossible.

Comment: maybe you can compare words and look for Levenshtein distance : this is used for Spelling error detection/correction

Comment: maybe this help : leetcode senetence similarity https://medium.com/@rebeccahezhang/leetcode-737-sentence-similarity-ii-2ca213f10115